# Java heap space out of memory when trying to start a fabric minecraft mod i made

Tags: java, heap-memory, minecraft-fabric

I have this mad anoying issue where, when i launch a fabric project for testing my mod, i run into an out of memory error on the datafixer minecraft thing.
Where is the full exception :

```
[31mUnable to build datafixers
[m java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1807) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[34m[12:32:03][m [31m[Worker-Bootstrap-4/ERROR][m [36m(Minecraft)[m [31mUnable to build datafixers
[m java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1807) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Functions.comp(Functions.java:27) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Comp.lambda$one$2(Comp.java:43) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Comp$$Lambda$1688/0x00000008011b76a8.apply(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[?:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Comp.one(Comp.java:43) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$One.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:651) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$OrElse.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:571) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Comp.one(Comp.java:43) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$One.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:651) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$OrElse.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:571) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Comp.one(Comp.java:43) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$One.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:651) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$OrElse.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:571) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Comp.one(Comp.java:43) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$One.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:651) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$OrElse.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:571) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Comp.one(Comp.java:43) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$One.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:651) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$OrElse.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:571) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Comp.one(Comp.java:43) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$One.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:651) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$OrElse.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:571) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Comp.one(Comp.java:43) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$One.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:651) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$OrElse.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:571) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Comp.one(Comp.java:43) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$One.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:651) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$OrElse.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:571) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Comp.one(Comp.java:43) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$One.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:651) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.PointFreeRule$OrElse.rewrite(PointFreeRule.java:571) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.datafixers.functions.Comp.one(Comp.java:43) ~[datafixerupper-4.0.26.jar:?]
```

It does not happen when i don't put anything to register in my onInitialize method.

It was working well a day ago.

you can find the entire mod code here : [link to my mod's github](https://github.com/belzoriun/rifts)

I can't make any progress with this ... so this is critical.

Please, if someone have any clue or fix to give me, it would be nice.

Comment: Please add your code snippets that cause the error. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind !
I found it, i tryed to generate an int property from 0 to int max

Comment: That's many objects!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).